# How to count different conditions' results in one line

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table like below

| myid | status | owner | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a001 | open | John | 0901 |
| a001 | cncl | John | 0901 |
| a002 | open | John | 0901 |
| a002 | open | Andy | 0901 |
| a003 | open | John | 0901 |
| a003 | open | John | 0902 |
| a003 | open | John | 0902 |

I want the relust:

| myid | count(1) | count(2) | count(3) | count(4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a001 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| a002 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| a003 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 |

- count(1) is the result : number of the myid
- count(2) is the result : number of the myid which the status is 'cncl'
- count(3) is the result : number of the myid which the  owner is 'John'
- count(4) is the result : number of the myid which the   date is '0901'

is there any simple function to get the result?

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use conditional aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (myid, status, owner, datum) as
  2  (select
  3  'a001', 'open', 'John', '0901' from dual union all select
  4  'a001', 'cncl', 'John', '0901' from dual union all select
  5  'a002', 'open', 'John', '0901' from dual union all select
  6  'a002', 'open', 'Andy', '0901' from dual union all select
  7  'a003', 'open', 'John', '0901' from dual union all select
  8  'a003', 'open', 'John', '0902' from dual union all select
  9  'a003', 'open', 'John', '0902' from dual
 10  )
```

Query:

```
 11  select myid,
 12    count(*),
 13    sum(case when status = 'cncl' then 1 else 0 end) cncl,
 14    sum(case when owner  = 'John' then 1 else 0 end) john,
 15    sum(case when datum  = '0901' then 1 else 0 end) datum
 16  from test
 17  group by myid
 18  order by myid;

MYID   COUNT(*)       CNCL       JOHN      DATUM
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
a001          2          1          2          2
a002          2          0          1          2
a003          3          0          3          1

SQL>
```